# chmod for run file

Tags: mysql, shell, cron

**Sorry,But i know english a little bit :) , Thank help.** Bash I need to delete data 90 day ago and save Data Delete

Next > condition crontab -e

```
* * * * * /root/file.sh >> /root/textsh.txt

Result : cat textsh.txt
         []
```

**I learning shell,cron,other**  But,i concentrate to learn i hope to nice programmer

```
chmod +x file.sh
```

Comment: Cron job output is redirected in `/root/textsh.txt` file but you are checking `text.txt`. You should check output in `textsh.txt` not in `text.txt`

Comment: so sorry,misprint ,i will check textsh.txt but no data

Comment: Try changing cron job to `* * * * * /root/file.sb >> /root/textsh.txt 2>&1` so that error message are also logged in into text file.

Comment: i try , so result bin/sh: /root/file.sb: No such file or directory. can u help me

Comment: /bin/sh: /root/file.sh: Permission denied

Comment: User does not have permission to execute the file. Run command `chmod +x /root/file.sh` to give execute permission to file. Also change the name of the command in cron job from `/root/file.sb` to `/root/file.sh` (seems another typo in your question).

Comment: Wow! thank you very much. and so sorry i'm soft language english

Comment: Good to know it solved your issue :).

Comment: I have to learn English to communicate :) trying ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the execute permission on /root/file.sh?  If it is not executable, you will end up with a zero byte /root/textsh.txt file.

Run /root/file.sb on the command prompt before putting it on cron.  Also, it is good to send cronjob's errors to a separate file.

Comment: i will try TT i'm newbie+

Comment: it's ok thank you, Answer chmod +x file.sh